# How to setup caching DB based on update schedule

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, amazon-redshift

I use an external datasource for one of my applications. That database gets updated nightly, but after the update, it is static. (AWS, Redshift, PostgreSQL).

In ColdFusioin I had been caching some of the queries in my app for small periods of time 30 minutes just so things run faster. But I got to thinking, if the database doesn't get updated but daily, couldn't I do something like `cachedAfter` the current date 8:00 AM or something like that? Then every day at 8:00 AM the caches get cleared?

My understanding is, it will only cache the queries if they are exactly the same. But what is not clear is with something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE a = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.a#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_int" />
```

If the value of `a` changes in the arguments, CF is smart enough to treat it as a different query, correct? The docs says it will only cache if the query is the same, but does that mean the same setup or the same everything include param values?

If this is true, it seems it would it be smart to just cache all the queries at a certain time each day. I would get huge performance gains as the Redshift database while fast, does take processing time on some of these larger queries. What pitfalls might I encounter with that?

Comment: The query will only be cached if everything in the cfquery is the same. If `a` is different then it will be a different cache.

Comment: So if you have static DB, is there a reason you wouldn't cache the queries?

Comment: I don't know how many or how large the queries you are talking about are. The only consideration I can think of would be memory space on the ColdFusion server to store _n_ queries in the cache.

Comment: What would that be called so I can read about it. It seems like CF would be smart enough to handle that. I mean there are memory limits for the app as well as # of cached query limits in the settings for the server. It seems like memory for a cached query wouldn't take precedent over running the app itself.

Comment: @Leeish - Side note, do not forget you can always verify whether a particular query was cached by dumping the query "result" attribute, ie `resultName.cached`

Comment: @Leigh, thx did not know that.

Comment: It is dependent on too many factors to list here. This is one of those things that is unique to your environment and configuration. I'm not saying it won't handle it well but just something you will need to keep in mind if your server starts "hanging" and other operating systems processes don't have enough memory for their operations. Again, not trying to keep you from trying this. But you will need to do some load testing to see how _your_ system handles it. Read some here - [Performance tuning for ColdFusion apps](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html)

Comment: Note: that article I referenced talks about ColdFusion caching about half-way down the page.

Comment: When thinking of "first in first out" as would be the case with caching, do you know if CF is smart enough to prioritize expired queries using `cachedWithin` vs still valid queries using `cachedAfter`? I could see using `cachedWithin` for some things, but if the `cachedAfter` query was first in and the `cachedWithin` query has expired, I'd want to give the `cachedWithin` one the boot even if it wasn't first in.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. All of it is really being handled by the JVM. So you might be able to find some information relating to Java or JEE and my guess would be that the ColdFusion server would work in a similar way.

Comment: You might want to consider caching the generated html as a flat file, if possible in your application. Then you don't have to to worry about memory space. Also this bypasses the time CF has to process that query to generate the output html.

Comment: @Jules if this was a website if think of it but this is a web app and even though there are certain queries within a process that can be cached there are others that cannot that run from a different DB.

Comment: Thinking out loud here... have a scheduled task run the queries and store the results in separate/smaller/more efficient database tables (perhaps a different db server). Then have CF access those stored results with a much simpler query, you would select the whole table.